# Cacheable blocks independent of query params

Tags: magento2, cache

Hello #realmagento folks,

How to make page blocks cacheable based on the store-id & request-URI (irrelevant of query params though) in Magento 2?

- /some-page -> blocks are cached
- /some-page?abc=xyz -> blocks are not cached (but I want it to be cached)

**Note** that block caching stops working as soon as some query string params are added.

Thanks

Comment: I think you can find your answer there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410713/how-do-i-get-magento-to-serve-up-the-cached-version-of-the-page-when-i-have-uniq

Answer (score 0):

Magento2 does not have "not cacheable" blocks. If you set cacheable to false then all pages with this block will be not cacheable.
If the content of your block is user specific you should mark the block as `$_isScopePrivate = true.` and the block will be delivered over Ajax.
If the content is not user-specific you need to render it by JS.